# How I can write my a regexp to find @xyz @xyz asdf?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a regexp in js for finding a test string and the test string is "@xyz @xyz asdf" and it should not detect plain text. I'm trying with

```
/\s+([@][\w_-]+[\s]{0,1}([A-Za-z0-9@.]+))/
```

Comment: Please edit your question and clearly show the input along with what you are trying to match in that input.

Comment: If you're trying to find a specific string why not just search for /@xyz @xyz asdf/

Comment: not the same string in that format

Comment: can you tell me your rules for example: 1- Must start with @. 2-Can't contains numbers ... etc

Comment: And it should be find firstname with @ or firstname lastname with @

Comment: Please list some examples ([edit] your question to include them) of sample strings and matched values. Maybe even some "this should not match".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what exactly you ask, but based on the regex you provided, a small modification could suffice:

```
var rgx = /\s*@\w+\s?(?:\w|@)+\b/i;
```

https://regex101.com/r/X89dpx/1/

or if the second word must have @:

```
var rgx = /@\w+\s?(?![^@]+)[^\s]*/gi;
"some long sentence @xyz @xyz asdf".match(rgx);//["@xyz @xyz"]
```

In case you want to match @somename lastname separately:

```
var rgx  = /@\w+\s?(?=[^@]+)[^\s]*/gi;
```

https://regex101.com/r/mBt2wH/2/

Could be bit more concise:

```
var rgx = /@\w+(?:\s[^\s@]+)?/gi;
```

https://regex101.com/r/mBt2wH/3/

Comment: It should detect the one string after the space with @

Comment: so my second solution is what you want then. Based on your own description.

Comment: actually my problem is I have @mentions in my app for that I need to get only mentioned users from message. User may have both firstname and lastname or only firstname

Comment: ok so my first solution is working for this. here https://regex101.com/r/X89dpx/4/

Comment: But it will break for this one ```@mention @mention  asdff ``` it should match both.

Comment: this does not: https://regex101.com/r/mBt2wH/2/      See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what exactly u want but can u try this regex.
I understand that:

@xyz

@xyz asdf

```
/^[\@]([a-z|A-Z]*)([ ]*[a-z|A-Z]*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?:@[^\s$]+\s){2}[\w]+$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/1Ov6ob/1/

Explaination:

Twice: @ followed by at least one among non-space and non-end (therefore letters, symbols)

Then a "word" composed of at least one of word-character \w : [a-zA-Z0-9_] or you may prefer [^\s$]. Though in a comment you also accepted a trailing space so maybe [\w\s]. Tweak this last part basing on what you really need.

All followed by end of line or string. This prevents matching something broke in more lines.